# Protocols with optional properties?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, properties, compiler-warnings

The short version is that I have a protocol which has an optional parameter. When I build a class that implements it with the iPhone SDK 3.x it compiles just fine, with no errors or warnings. When I used the 2.x SDK I get the following warning:

```
Class.m:68: warning: property 'field' requires method '-field' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation
```

It works just fine in both cases.

So two questions:

1. What is the right way to fix the warning? I added `@dynamic` to the implementation which isn't really correct as the property really isn't there.
2. Why does work in SDK 3.x but not 2.x? The docs say "On Mac OS X v10.5, protocols may not include optional declared properties." Clearly that's not exactly the case here.

Here's a quick sample of the kind of code I have to make things a little more obvious if I wasn't completely clear.

```
@protocol MyProtocol
  @required
    - (void) method:(NSString*)param;
  @optional
    @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString* field;
@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject<MyProtocol> {
}
- (void) method:(NSString*)param;
@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPhone SDK is not exactly identical to any paricular version of Mac OS X. Clearly a newer version of the toolset is included with SDK 3 that's more similar to the one from Snow Leopard.

Comment: I think you're right. Do you know of a preferred way to eliminate the warning? Or is it just a case of "don't do it" using SDK 2.x?

Comment: Well, don't do it or make peace with the warning. It's a feature that's new in SDK 3.

Answer (score 1):

The simnple way to remove the warning is to add

@dynamic field;

to your implementation.  That tells the compiler that you will provide the implementation dynamically, which you wont, becuase its an optional property, but that should shut the compiler up.

Answer (score 0):

The @optional was introduced in Objective-C 2.0 so it won't be applicable for older versions of the SDK. Your best bet is to determine whether it should be present (probably not) and then #ifdef that around with

```
#if __OBJC2__
@optional
@property ...
#endif
```

Then it should only compile under an OBJC2, and it won't be present in the older systems as part of the protocol itself.

Comment: I believe all versions of iPhone SDK support Objective-C 2.0, which was released with Leopard in late 2007. Recall that the iPhone SDK was not released until mid-2008.